# Share one layer between many projects in QField Cloud

Tags: geopackage, qfield, qfield-cloud

Is it possible to have several different projects access and update the same layer/geopackage file on the cloud? I.e two different projects include the same layer, and when it is updated on one the changes also affects the second project.